# Eclipse (CDT) auto-format on save is different than auto-format explicitely

Tags: eclipse, formatter

I use the auto-formatter in eclipse an like it very much. 
The problem is, that it does not alway behave as it is expected to:
For template parameters I have configured it to have no spaces after and before the braces, like `<int>`. This works well for built-in types, but it does not for self-defined types like `uint16_t` from `#include <cstdint>`. 
The weird thing here is, that it works with the shortcut ctrl+shift+f, but it does not work with "format on save". `<uint16_t>` is transformed into `< uint16_t >`.

How can that be fixed?